# I am trying to create my first excel macro for my job, but I am getting errors

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Microsoft Excel with 365.

This Macro is for a weekly/monthly report for my new job.

I first have it setting up two blank columns in Columns A and C.
Then I rename these columns to what I want. In this case 'Updates' and 'NPI Match'.

Then I have it filtering out some insurance plans in one of my other columns that I do not want data on.

I open up an entirely different workbook with data on eligible Prescribers, I copy column 2 of this workbook which has a list of NPI numbers of our eligible prescribers.

I go back to my original workbook, which has a column B that has a list of prescribers who are both eligible and non-eligible, I create a new sheet and paste the copied column into the new sheet. I name this sheet 'NPI'.

I then go back to 'sheet 1' of the original workbook and go into 'Cell C2' (the entire first row are headers) of Column C. In this cell I make a countif formula of =COUNTIF(NPI,B2) and hit enter. Then I autofill that column all the way down.

Now this is grabbing the eligible prescribers from the 'NPI' sheet as well as the data out of the 'B2 column' next to it and comparing.  I then filter out the non-eligible prescribers (0 in filter) out of this new column and I am only left with the eligible prescribers (1 in filter).

I end my macro after doing all of these steps, but when I try and run the macro on a new date of the same data, I get the following error.

"Run-time error '9':

Subscript out of range"

I run my debugger, and it shows me this in the link below. Any clue on what is going on and/or how to fix it?

```
Selection.Copy
    Windows("11-14-2023macrotestsheet1.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="NPI", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=Sheet2!R1C1:R1048571C1"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(NPI,B2)"
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.FillDown
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
```

Am I doing something wrong with my macro? I feel like it may be an error from one workbook communicating to the other when I grab my NPI list from the second workbook. Let me know.

Comment: You have no workbook named `macrotestsheet1.xlsx` open.

Comment: Hmm, I do though. At least I thought I did.

Comment: It may be a little daunting at first, but highly suggest you read [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), which should hopefully help you to use variables, avoid using `Activate`, and generally make your code more robust. Instead of using `Windows`, use a `Workbook` variable. `Dim wb As Workbook`, `Set wb = Workbooks("macrotestsheet1.xlsx")` ... which is going to fail with the same error if you don't have a `macrotestsheet1.xlsx` workbook open.

Comment: I have the macro working now, but it only works up unto the point of where it has to open the 2nd workbook, copy the 2nd column from it, and paste it into the original workbook but just onto it's own separate sheet. It is not grabbing the data from that sheet and pasting it into my Column C of the original sheet though. I am lost.

Comment: Most likely you have an instance of `Range` or `Columns` that is not fully qualified with the `Workbook` and `Worksheet` it belongs to, but it'd be better to create a [reprex] so we can help.

Comment: Can you help me do that @BigBen?

Comment: It is not my intention to pick down on you, but please read the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for this site, especially regarding [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). It is your task to provide a [mre]. And please, don't write it as a page in a diary. Instead, show the code you have now, and explain what it doesn't do that it should.

Comment: Oh, and one important rule: never post code or error messages as images, instead post those always as text.

Comment: Alright, I am new to this site, so I am still learning how things work. Thank you for the information, Tom.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question with code, instead of posting code in comments.

Comment: Alright, I updated my topic with the code that is going wrong. It is transferring my code from the 2nd workbook to the first, but it is having the problems copying the row that I transferred into the COUNTIF function. Any idea why?

Comment: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(NPI,B2)"` requires RC notation ie `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(NPI,RC[-1])"`